# Error Sqoop mysql driver load exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sqoop, mysql-connector

Even after adding connector "mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar" in SQOOP_HOME/lib

```
 sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/tweets --username root --password ***** --table tweetcount --staging-table tweetcount_stage -m 4 --export-dir hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/tweetcount
```

Running Sqoop command shows following error

```
15/08/01 21:38:13 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:856)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:744)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:64)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: Please check on the Sqoop release page regarding the compatibility of sqoop version and the Jdbc version.

Answer (score 0):

SET HADOO_CLASSPATH to the mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar location.

Answer (score 0):

I simply copied my connector to sqoop lib folder.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 8.0\mysql-connector-java-8.0.24 to C:\sqoop-1.4.7\lib